# Python ftplib - uploading multiple files?

Tags: python, ftplib

I've googled but I could only find how to upload one file... and I'm trying to upload all files from local directory to remote ftp directory. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dnozay/37e8148ee748068afb91 - recursive copy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

with the loop?

**edit**: in universal case uploading only files would look like this:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('path/to/local/dir'):
    for fname in files:
        full_fname = os.path.join(root, fname)
        ftp.storbinary('STOR remote/dir' + fname, open(full_fname, 'rb'))
```

Obviously, you need to look out for name collisions if you're just preserving file names like this.

Comment: It's script that would upload website to host... so lets say i have website in some directory on my local hard drive and i want to upload its contents but NOT with directory, only files so my website after being uploaded will be accessible from myaddress.com instead of myaddress.com/somedirectory

Comment: do you need to close the file?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Python-scriptlines required to make upload-files from JSON-Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805778/python-scriptlines-required-to-make-upload-files-from-json-call) and next [FTPlib-operation: why some uploads, but others not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049403/ftplib-operation-why-some-uploads-but-others-not)

Although a different starting position than your question, in the **Answer** of that first url you see an example construction to upload by ftplib a json-file plus an xml-file: look at scriptline 024 and further.

In the second url you see some other aspects related to upload of more files.

Also applicable for other file-types than json and xml, obviously with a different 'entry' before the 2 final sections which define and realize the FTP_Upload-function.

Answer (score -3):

Create a FTP batch file (with a list of files that you need to transfer). Use python to execute ftp.exe with the "-s" option and pass in the list of files.

This is kludgy but apparently the FTPlib does not have accept multiple files in its STOR command.

Here is a sample ftp batch file.

*

```
OPEN inetxxx 
myuser mypasswd 
binary 
prompt off 
cd ~/my_reg/cronjobs/k_load/incoming 
mput *.csv 
bye
```

- If the above contents were in a file called "abc.ftp" - then my ftp command would be

  ftp -s abc.ftp

Hope that helps.

Comment: I implied an myftp.ftp file as a 'batch' file and not an MSDOS specific ".bat"  file.

This file will contain a list of ftp commands (and not OS-specific commands).

For example , here's one of mine -

OPEN inetxxx
myuser
mypasswd
binary
prompt off
cd ~/my_reg/cronjobs/k_load/incoming
mput *.csv
bye

Comment: this way is not portable, and why use another ftp client when Python has its own. For multiple, do it the way like SilentGhost did.